# Ensure Start-Process starts and finishes in order

Tags: powershell, sequence, start-process

PowerShell script has the following

```
Start-Process "D:\Script\EMAIL_Snapshot_Done.bat" $date, $scr_comp
Start-Process "D:\Script\BATCH_gup.bat"
```

How to ensure that first Start-Process starts and finishes BEFORE second Start-Process begins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this should do the trick.

```
Start-Process "D:\Script\EMAIL_Snapshot_Done.bat" $date, $scr_comp -Wait
```

You would have found this information on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx)

[`Wait-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849813.aspx) could also help but the simplicity of `-Wait` should not compare.